# How can I position this div where I want it?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am having a hard time positioning this div where I want it.Please see the following code pen:

https://codepen.io/bmecler/pen/abbYMqv

The div that says 'Now', I'm trying to place it in the opposite corner of where it is now. Same type of positioning, overhanging top right of the entire container div.

I have tried re-working the entire way I make this "card" several times. This is the closet I have been able to get to what I want..

Thanks in advance for any help!

```css
.card_small_container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.card_small_timeFrame {
  padding: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  float: right;
  float: right;
  margin-left: -1px;
  margin-top: -1px;
}

.card_small {
  flex-direction: row;
  border: 1px solid #CAD0D2;
  border-radius: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 5px;
  position: relative;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.card_small_title {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: black;
  padding: 2px;
  text-align: center;
}

.card_small_descriptionIcon {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}

.card_small_value {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  flex-grow: 1;
  color: #57727C;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #EEF3F5;
}

span.isNow {
  background-color: #E64A19;
  color: white;
  padding: 2px 4px 1px 4px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

span.legendHighlight {
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -o-border-radius: 5px;
  -ms-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/dcd23ccc83.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="card_small_container">
  <div class="card_small">
    <div class="card_small_container card--fixedWidth">
      <div style="background-color: #8ed8a2;" class="icon fas fa-phone-alt card_small_descriptionIcon"></div>
      <div class="card_small_value">17</div>
    </div>
    <div class="card_small_title">My Cards Title</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card_small_timeFrame"><span class="legendHighlight isNow">Now</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do u want the "Now" orange buttom form right side corner?

Answer (score 1):

Position absolute is relevant to its containing container (the first parent element with a position other than static).

The container element `.card_small_container` needs to be changed to "inline-flex". Otherwise it will expand to the entire width of the screen and the orange button will be displayed at the far right end of the screen.

Floating elements is not needed when using `position:absolute` because they are used to "relatively" move an element. Since absolute required specific positioning, float will not be needed.

You can change your code to this:

```css
.card_small_container {
  /*display: flex;*/
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  position: relative;
}

.card_small_timeFrame {
  padding: 1px;
  position: absolute;
 /* float: right;
  float: right;*/
  margin-left: -1px;
  margin-top: -1px;
  right: 0;
}

.card_small {
  flex-direction: row;
  border: 1px solid #CAD0D2;
  border-radius: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 5px;
  position: relative;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.card_small_title {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: black;
  padding: 2px;
  text-align: center;
}

.card_small_descriptionIcon {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}

.card_small_value {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  flex-grow: 1;
  color: #57727C;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #EEF3F5;
}

span.isNow {
  background-color: #E64A19;
  color: white;
  padding: 2px 4px 1px 4px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

span.legendHighlight {
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -o-border-radius: 5px;
  -ms-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/dcd23ccc83.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="card_small_container">
  <div class="card_small">
    <div class="card_small_container card--fixedWidth">
      <div style="background-color: #8ed8a2;" class="icon fas fa-phone-alt card_small_descriptionIcon"></div>
      <div class="card_small_value">17</div>
    </div>
    <div class="card_small_title">My Cards Title</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card_small_timeFrame"><span class="legendHighlight isNow">Now</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You may want to also address that `float: right` on that element is not needed (nor needed twice). And also explain `display: inline-flex`.